# na.omit () wont remove the NAs from data

Tags: r, mean, na, tiff, shapefile

I am trying to extract values from a box imposed on a .tiff map file on R studio, and calculate a mean from each box. There are NAs produced from each box which I need to remove in order to calculate a mean.

I have loaded my tiff file, set minimum and maximum values and plotted the map:

```
DEM <- raster("del15N_130_raster.tif")

DEM<- setMinMax(DEM)

plot(DEM)
```

I then need to impose a box onto the map and extract the values from the box by

```
AntC <- read_sf("shp/Antartica_typeC.shp")
# Plot the raster with the shape file box
plot(AntC, add = T)
# get mean values from shape
vals <- terra::extract(DEM, AntC, na.rm=TRUE )
vals_mean <- mean(vals$layer)
```

As there are NAs produced from the map values, I recieve the error

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(vals$layer) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I have tried the following options

```
na.omit(DEM)
vals_mean <- mean(vals$layer, na.rm=TRUE))
vals<-vals[!is.na(vals)]
meanvals <- terra::extract(
  DEM, 
  AntC, 
  fun="mean", na.rm=TRUE
)
```

I still have NAs in 'vals' and i still get the same error

Comment: You need to assign the result, `DEM <- na.omit(DEM)`. Running `na.omit(DEM)` will print the result but not keep it, just like `mean(1:10)` will print `5.5` but `5.5` isn't stored anywhere.

Comment: If `mean(vals$layer, na.rm = TRUE)` is failing then it's possible you have other, non-`na` non-numeric non-logical contents.

Comment: Your attempts are also inconsistent about what types of data you are handling. `vals<-vals[!is.na(vals)]` should work if `vals` is a vector, not a list or data frame. `vals_mean <- mean(vals$layer, na.rm=TRUE))` should work of `vals` is a list or data frame with a column named `layer`, not a vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
vals_mean <- terra::extract(DEM, AntC, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

If there are still `NA`s, then that could be because the polygons (boxes) are outside the raster, or they are very small. In the latter case, you can solve your problem with

```
vals_mean <- terra::extract(DEM, AntC, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, exact=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thankyou so much the first line solved it!